# Moment theorem for Fourier's coefficient

Tags: fourier-analysis

I would like to show that for $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a continuous $2 \pi$ - periodic function  if
$$
\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \ \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f\left(t\right)e^{int}\text{d}t=0
$$
Then $f=0$
I know a close result that is
$$
\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \int_{a}^{b}t^nf\left(t\right)\text{d}t=0 \Rightarrow f=0
$$
Is there a simple way to show this ?

Comment: What are your assumptions on $f?$

Comment: The reason I am asking is because as the question stands now, your statement does not seem to be true. 
For example, if $f(t) = e^{it},$  then $\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(t)e^{i n t} dt =0$ for $n \geq 0.$

Comment: Yes you are right, i've edited

Comment: Hint: what is $ \overline{\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(t) e^{int} dt}$ if $f(t)$ is real? What does this say about the Fourier coefficients of $f?$

Comment: (If you need more assistance, tell me and I will give a further hint)

Comment: If you know that a continuous function can be uniformly approximated by trigonometric polynomials and that you can interchange limit and integral in case of uniform convergence of integrands then you are done.

Comment: Have you had a course in Complex Analysis?

Comment: Only with Laurent series, holomorphism, residue etc

Comment: Do you know Liouville's Theorem where you show that every bounded entire function is constant? A modification of that theorem can give you what you want, where you show that if an entire function is uniformly bounded on a sequence of circles (or squares) centered at the origin with the sequence of radii tending to $\infty$, then the function is constant. Interested?

Comment: Yes, but i dont know about the theorem

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate over $[0,2\pi]$ because $f$ is periodic. Consider the function
$$
         F(\lambda)=\frac{1}{1-e^{2\pi i\lambda}}\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(x)e^{i\lambda x}dx.
$$
This is a holomorphic function on $\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{Z}$. Suppose that $\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(x)e^{inx}dx=0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. Then $F(\lambda)$ extends to an entire function of $\lambda$ because $1-e^{2\pi i\lambda}$ has first order zeros at $\lambda=0,\pm 1,\pm 2,\cdots$. You can show that $F(\lambda)$ is uniformly bounded on all squares centered at the origin of width $n+1/2$. That is enough to be able use the Cauchy integral representation of $F(\lambda)$ inside such squares in order to conclude that $F$ is uniformly bounded on $\mathbb{C}$ and, hence, must be a constant $K$. The constant $K$ must be $0$, which can be seen by examining $\lim_{r\uparrow\infty}F(ir)$. Therefore
$$
      \int_{0}^{2\pi} f(x)e^{i\lambda x}dx = 0,\;\;\; \lambda\in\mathbb{C}.
$$
All derivatives of the above are $0$ at $\lambda=0$, which gives
$$
        \int_{0}^{2\pi}x^n f(x)dx =0,\;\;\; n=0,1,2,3,\cdots.
$$
So $f=0$ a.e. by what you know.